# Where-Object -and -or issues

Tags: powershell

I have an error (or situation) that is driving me crazy.
I have a script in which I use a piped where-object to select certain accounts of users.

```
$ExpirationDate = Get-ADUser -Filter {(PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) -and (Enabled -eq $true)}  -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Where-Object {($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' -lt $MaxDate) -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,OU=Service Accounts,*" -or $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,OU=Ressources,*")}enter code here
```

I have used something similar in other scripts and worked perfectly. However, in this particular case, if I run it till the "*-and*", I get 31 users. If then I add the first part of the "*-Or*", they go down to 26 but, if I add the second part, to reduce even more the number of users taken into account (the two *-or* are to filter certain OUs), I got again 31 users.

I have tried *()* to separate the *-or*, not use any *()*, and anything that I could imagine to get the real number, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Best regards

Comment: Change the `-or` to an `-and` - otherwise one of them is always true (the objects in the resource OU is not in the Service Accounts OU and vice versa).